# My actionscript is not running with my fla file

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript

My actionscript is not running with my fla file I have everything right for the coding for my maintimer but my timer on my fla file will not countdown, for some reason everytime I test it does nothing. please help with problem

```
package  {

import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.TimerEvent;
import flash.utils.Timer;
//import flash.events.ThrottleEvent;

public class MainTimer extends MovieClip {

    private var currentMin:int;
    private var currentSec:int;

    private var oneSecondTimer:Timer = new Timer(1000);
    public var timerHasStopped:Boolean = false;

    public function MainTimer(){
        // constructor code
        trace("The Main Timer is here");
        currentMin = 2; 
        currentSec = 5; 

        minBox.text = String(currentMin);
        if(currentSec < 10) {
            secBox.text = "0" + String(currentSec); //concatentate with leading zero
        }else{
        secBox.text = String(currentSec);
    }
    oneSecondTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER_COMPLETE, onTimerComplete);     
    oneSecondTimer.start();
  }//end function

    private function onTimerComplete(event:TimerEvent):void{

        currentSec = currentSec - 1;
        if (currentSec < 0){
            currentSec = 59;
            currentMin = currentMin - 1;
         }//end if
         if (currentMin < 0){
             currentMin = 0;
             currentSec = 0;
         }else{
             oneSecondTimer.start(); 
         }//end else
         //update display
        minBox.text = String(currentMin);
        secBox.text = String(currentSec);
        if(currentSec < 10){
            secBox.text = "0" + String(currentSec);
        }//end if

    }//end function

}}
```

Comment: Open the properties panel in Flash and add MainTimer in the box that says Class.

Answer (score 0):

You have to make sure your class `MainTimer` is linked to your document. Also, you had to add the elements to the stage with `addChild()` after create them.